# React Native TextInput does not display number type value

Tags: react-native

I have a pre-rendered value that always has to be a number type. I set the TextInput value to this number but it does not display in the input field unless I convert the number to a string. However, when the number is converted to a string  using `toString()` or `String(value)`, editing the TextInput by clearing out the field causes NaN to display in the field which becomes impossible to wipe out as it keeps recurring after every attempt.

Here is how the TextInput looks:

```
<TextInput value={5}/> 
//displays nothing in the field unless when like this: 

<TextInput value="5"/>

<TextInput value={value.toString()}/>  and <TextInput value={String(value}/> cause NaN when the field is cleared completely
```

It also does not emit a number value, but not rendering a number value is the more serious problem.

Please can anyone tell me how I can solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You could simplify this by using string literals.

You have

```
const [num, setNum] = React.useState(0);
```

And then,

```
<TextInput 
   keyboardType="numeric" 
   onChangeText={(newNum) => setNum(newNum)} 
   defaultValue={`${num}`} />
```

Answer (score 2):

> not rendering a number value is the more serious problem.

TextInput's value prop `type` is `string` ,that's why you must explicitly convert it while passing it as prop to your TextInput.

[for more info](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.6/textinput#value)

you can achieve this by using state and onTextChange method check code snippet.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet ,TextInput} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';


export default function App() {
  const [numValue,setNumValue] = React.useState(9991122)
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput value={numValue.toString()} keyboardType={'numeric'} style={{margin:100,borderWidth:2}} onChangeText={(e)=>setNumValue(e)}/> 
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
 
});
```

Comment: Thanks @muhammad. This worked for useState. However, I am using formik. Please do you know how I can use handleChange  to emit number instead of string? Or any other method?